# Java application with PowerPC JavaApplicationStub on Mac OS Lion

Tags: java, macos, osx-lion

I maintain a java app for Mac that was written back in the PPC days, and its user was happily running it under Rosetta until he upgraded to lion. We tried switching out the JavaApplicationStub binary in the app folder, but this changed nothing (still crossed-out icon in dock and error message about PPC support when launched). Restarted, still nothing.

Not sure what's going on here. I know the stub works, when I run itt from terminal the application runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, moving the app folder to another directory and back made the OS "notice" that the stub had been switched out. Mysterious. Perhaps someone with more MacOS knowledge can explain further.

Comment: Yes, there is some mysterious caching going on for files inside the .app folder. I've also found that renaming the .app also gets the OS to 'notice' changes.